# Problems with animation

Tags: probability-or-statistics, animation

I am trying to make a random walk simulation with `Animate`, but somehow it doesn't produce the animation I want.

```
SingleRandomWalk[k_] := Module[
  {pts = {{0, 0}}},
  Do[AppendTo[
    pts, {0, 
     pts[[i, 2]] + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1/k]]}], {i, 1,
     k}];
  Print[pts];
  Animate[
   Graphics[{PointSize[0.03], Point[pts[[i]]]}, Axes -> True, 
    AspectRatio -> 2, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-2, 2}}], {i, 1, k+1}, 
   DefaultDuration -> 1]]
SingleRandomWalk[5]
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
SingleRandomWalk[k_] := 
 Module[{pts = {{0, 0}}}, 
  Do[AppendTo[
    pts, {0, 
     pts[[i, 2]] + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1/k]]}], {i, 1,
     k}];
  Print[pts];
  Animate[
   Graphics[{PointSize[0.03], Point[pts[[i]]]}, Axes -> True, 
    AspectRatio -> 2, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-2, 2}}], {i, 1, 
    Length@pts, 1}, DefaultDuration -> 1]]
SingleRandomWalk[5]
```

You need `{i, 1, Length@pts, 1}` and not `{i, 1, Length@pts}` otherwise  Animate does not know it is discrete ! It will otherwise try to use continuous increments which does not work for `Part`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

In your code, the step of the variable of the animation is wrong. In the document, it says

> `Animate[expr,{u,Subscript[u, min],Subscript[u, max]}]`generates an animation of expr in which u varies **continuously** from Subscript[u, min] to Subscript[u, max].

which means that the variable of your code `i` in `Animate[...pts[[i]], {i, 1, k+1}]` is wrong as it can be decimal. You need to add a step such as `{i, 1, k+1, 1}`.

Comment: I get it know, thank you!